# Netbeans remote deployment on raspberrypi returns "make: Makefile: No such file or directory"

Tags: netbeans, sftp, remote-debugging

I was trying to run classic Blink program on raspberrypi by remotely deploying the code. This is the output that i got.

```
cd '/home/pi/Documents/netbeansProject/'
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug
make: Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'Makefile'.  Stop.
```

[All the files of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsRo3.png)

- All that i got to know after searching about this is make is not able to find the make file named 'Makefile' but i already have it in the project in the 'Important Files' section. Still make cannot find it..
- Now i tried to run a sample project following [netbeans tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/remotedev-tutorial.html#workflow) it also returns similar output.

```
cd '/home/pi/Documents/netbeansProject/Welcome_1/'
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug
make: Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'Makefile'.  Stop.
```

- The difference that  i noticed from the tutorial  is that i didn't get "Copying project files to..." in the output. Could it be that the Makefile never got to the rasberrypi and that's why it can't find it?
- I tried opening [remote terminal tab](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/remotedev-tutorial.html#terminal) and Netbeans gave error ['Local terminal is not supported on this system'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGtIa.png) even though i was opening a remote terminal. Although i can ssh into raspberrypi through local terminal easily. (Even with terminal provided in Netbeans)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did this and the issue is resolved

```
Project properties > Build > Build host > Host configuration check > Selected the host > Properties > Access project files via
```

and then selected SFTP(it was System level file sharing earlier) .

I don't know the difference between the two yet, but it worked for me. As i noted earlier, the files weren't copying to the remote host with SFTP.